# How to get permalink for every post in this shortcode function

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

I want to get the permalink of the images that shown on the home page, so that when someone clicks on the image redirects to its full post.

```
add_shortcode( 'zee_recent_works', function( $atts, $content= null ){
  ob_start();

  $atts = shortcode_atts(array(
    'slides'        => 2,
    'title'         => '',
    'description'   => ''
    ), $atts);

  extract($atts);

  $item_per_slide   = 4;

  $args             =  array(
    'numberposts'   =>  $item_per_slide*$slides,
    'orderby'       =>  'menu_order',
    'order'         =>  'ASC',
    'post_type'     =>  'zee_portfolio'
    );

  $portfolios = get_posts( $args );

  $i      = 1;
  $j      = 1;
  $count  = count($portfolios);

  if ($count>0) {
    ?>
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div id="scroller" class="carousel slide">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <?php

          foreach( $portfolios as $key=>$value ) {

            if( (($key+1)%($item_per_slide)==0) || $j== $count) {
              $lastContainer= true;
            } else {
              $lastContainer= false;
            }

            if($i==1){
              ?>
              <div class="item <?php echo ($key==0)? 'active': ''; ?>">
                <div class="row">
                  <?php
                }
                ?>
                <div class="col-md-<?php echo round(12/$item_per_slide) ?>">
                  <div class="portfolio-item">
                  <div class="item-inner">
                    <?php 
                    echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $value->ID, array(400,400), array( 
                      'class' => "img-responsive", 
                      'alt' => trim(strip_tags( $value->post_title )),
                      'title' => trim(strip_tags( $value->post_title ))
                      )); 
                      ?>
                      <h5>
                        <?php echo $value->post_title; ?>
                      </h5>
                      <div class="overlay">
                        <?php 
                        $full_img = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($value->ID), 'full');
                        $img_src= $full_img[0];
                        ?>
                        <a class="" title="<?php echo $value->post_title; ?>" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="prettyPhoto"></a>   
                      </div>
                    </div><!--.item-inner-->
                    </div><!--.portfolio-item-->
                  </div>    
                  <?php
                  if(($i == $item_per_slide) || $lastContainer) {
                    ?>
                  </div><!--/.row-->
                </div><!--/.col-xs-->
                <?php
                $i=0;
              }
              $i++;
              $j++;
            }
            ?>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div><!--/.col-md-12-->
      <?php
    }

    return ob_get_clean();
  });
```

and the link is there:

```
<a class="" title="<?php echo $value->post_title; ?>" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="prettyPhoto"></a>
```

where the permalink should work but its not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `the_permalink()` you can try `get_permalink($value->ID)`

final line should be

```
<a class="" title="<?php echo $value->post_title; ?>" href="<?php echo get_permalink($value->ID); ?>" rel="prettyPhoto" ></a>
```

Hope it helps :)

Thanks.